# Titanium connect Android phone Nexus 4

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy, nexus-4

Hello everyone I have a problem to connect my phone Nexus 4 with Titanium studio.

When I go to "Titanium Android Application Installer" Titanium does not detect my phone in the category   seetings> device.

I have enabled the USB Debugging option and I allowed unknown applications on my phone. 
My computer does detect the phone but not titanium

seetings :
Computer: Windows 8 
TItanium Studio: 3.2.0 
Phone Nexus 4.4.2

Use the framework Alloy

Comment: Do you have the android drivers? have you tried other phones?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

my drivers were out of date.